# Java Resetting private static member when all class instances are out of scope

Tags: java, class, static, instance

Hi I want to give a static private member to my class to keep track of the number of class objects created but I also want to dispose of it and reset when all the class instances are out of scope. Thing is easier for my case because I dont have to handle nested scopes. i.e. all instances are created at the same level:

```
if (true) {
    MyClass();  // Count 1
    MyClass();  // Count 2
}
if (true) {
    MyClass();  // Count 1
    MyClass();  // Count 2
}
```

I can of course easily add a reset to the last line of every scope, but is there any programmatic way to be implemented in MyClass to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Java has no deconstructors like C++/Objective-C and you can't dispose of a static member because Java has no delete/release/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java offers no reliable way of knowing exactly when all the objects go out of scope. Moreover, simply adding a call of `MyClass.staticReset()` to the end of each scope may not do the trick, if the function returns before the scope ends, or throws an exception.

An reliable solution would be adding the call to the `finally` block enclosing the scope of your variables:

```
if (someConditionIsTrue) try {
    MyClass();  // Count 1
    MyClass();  // Count 2
} finally {
    MyClass.staticReset();
}
```

Note that keeping the count in the static memory may become problematic in concurrent environments. A better option would be creating some object representing the "scope" explicitly, registering instances with it, and then calling `reset()` on it in the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks, so I take it as no automatic way to detect objects out of scope in java.

Comment: @user1589188 Correct - that's a consequence of having garbage collection.